# Equivalent resistance for a complex circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, symmetry, electrical-resistance

The problem is to find a equivalent resistance for the system below (resistance are all same).

[image]

I tied a mixture between the Kennely theorem and the laws of Kirchoff's, but i didn't find an optimal solution of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to observe is that the scheme is symmetrical. It means, besides other things, that the potentials are equivalent at the mirrored points, and you can just exclude the resistor in the very middle. If the current through it is non-zero, which direction would it have and why is it not the opposite?

[image: Crucial insight about the symmetry]

Moreover, as one could witness soon, *all* the resistors on the horizontal line won't have any current through them.

Indeed, you are left with two identical parallel branches of resistance say $R_x$ each, so the overall resistance would be $R_x/2$.

[image: Folding the circuit]

But the same logic about the symmetry could now be applied to each of these branches!

[image: Final cleanup]

That makes the answer just R/2, where R is the resistance of a single resistor in that circuit. Now, if A and B were placed at another pair of this rhombus vertices, that'd be fun...

Comment: hello! thank you for your comment! what do you mean by the mirrored points? i didn't really understand why all the resistors on the horizontal line won't have any current through them. Can you explain more please

Comment: @ElBadanos It it not immediately obvious about *all* of them I'll admit. Focus on the one in the middle first. Regardless of which path the current would take in such circuit (we use a vertical line through A and B here as the axis of symmetry), the points the middlemost resistor is connected to are exactly the same. That means no current through it. After that, you can "fold" the circuit in two. I'll try to edit the post and add images if I can figure out how to do it :-)

Comment: OH ! i see!!! thank you! But my question now is why if two points are symetrical they have the same potential? (i am sorry if i seem like i know nothing in the subject, I am new to this and i kinda leaning it on my own)

Comment: Thank you so much by the way for your effort and your time!! to much appreciated !

Comment: Oh, that is quite a hard insight to gain. Unfortunately, the best explanation I've had - and can offer - is that in a symmetrical circuit current can't possibly have any "preference" in picking a side. Suppose you took out all the resistors from the right side and swapped them with the resistors on the left side: the current direction should now be reversed, because we've just mirrored the circuit, but the circuit is still the same given the resistors on the right and the left are identical! Only zero current can stay the same after this mirroring thought experiment, and thus it must be zero.

Comment: Oh! i see ! it's a fair explanation, at least we know it's true.

Comment: Ok, now i understand why we can remove all the resistors in the middle. But what do you mean by Rx? is Rx the equivalent resistor of the right set of resistors in the sheme?

Comment: Yup. Pretty much.

Comment: OK, now i understand what you did! that was brillant, the symetry really maked the problem so easy! thank you again for your time and effort.